# IOS - Saved image not showing up on Photos app

Tags: iphone, ios, image, save

I am making an iOS app that saves an image of given URL.
I used the following code.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
      UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl]]];

      NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

      // Let's save the file into Document folder.
      NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

      NSLog(@"saving jpg");
      NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.jpg",docDir];
      NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
      [data2 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];

      NSLog(@"saving image done");
}
```

The image is saved successfully after calling this method.
Since I use iPhone simulator, I can see the image is saved my local Library folder.
However, when I open Photos (iPhone navie app) from the simulator, it doesn't detect the image I just saved. 
When I save an image from Safari and open Photos app, it detects the image correctly.
But why can't it detect the image I saved thru my ios app? Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How come/why do you think or assume any image written to a random location should be known about by the Photos app? That's just nonsense. Use the [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW29) instead.

Comment: @user2062024 I don't think so.

Comment: Yes its is possible. The app `Zedge` (wallpapers) does it.

Comment: Oops, accidentally deleted my original comment.. anyways I think this works. http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/